# Binary search not returning correct value

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I'm implementing the binary search algorithm in C++, but the algorithm isn't returning the correct value. The code can be found [here](http://goo.gl/FHHp5).

```
template<class T>
int binary_search(T search_value, T search_array[]) {

    int mid; /* The middle element of the remaining array to be searched. */
    int min = 0; /* The first index of the array. */
    /* This forumla gives us the size of the array. */
    int max = sizeof(search_array)/sizeof(search_array[0]);

    /* Continue searching until min >= max. */
    while (min < max) {
        /* Compute the value of mid using a formula that won't produce a number
         * larger than the maximum allowed value of an integer. */
        mid = (max-min)/2 + min;

        /* Depending the whether search_value is larger or smaller than the
         * value of whatever is at search_array[mid], set one of mid and max
         * equal to mid. */
        if (search_value > search_array[mid])
            min = mid + 1;
        else if (search_value < search_array[mid])
            max = mid + 1;
        else {
            return mid;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Given an array {0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9} and searching for 3, the function should return 2, the index of 3 in the array. My function is returning -1 though, which means 3 was not found in the array. Where's the problem?

Comment: Seems like a pretty trivial test case to step through in the debugger..

Comment: The first. Using sizeof-construction for receiving array size in function is a bad idea. Make one more argument in function, something like `int array_size`

Comment: Have you tried to debug?

Comment: If it is not homework: why don't you use STL [`binary_search`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af0b55bw(v=VS.71).aspx)?

Comment: @Naszta -- Because I'm trying to learn C++. :)

Comment: @mau5padd: in this case you should check the source of binary_search! :)

Comment: @Naszta: I wasn't aware I could do that!

Comment: I was just reading about binary search the other day in "Data Structures and Program Design in C" by Kruse/Leung/Tondo that "... the method dates back at least to 1946, but the first version free of errors and unnecessary restrictions seems to have appeared only in 1962". The idea is simple, but it isn't at all easy to get right...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int max = sizeof(search_array)/sizeof(search_array[0]);
```

This approach is not good to compute the size of the array, it works only in the function where you create your array.

Pass the size of your array as a parameter of your function, it's the easiest approach.

Comment: This worked. Just for giggles though, what is a better way to compute the size of an array? Essentially, all I did was move `sizeof(search_array)/sizeof(search_array[0])` into the `main` method and pass it to the function.

Comment: The problem is that `search_array` in your function is just a pointer to a memory address, not an array, thus this approach do not work except in the function where you create your array (in this case, the main). There is not a standard way to compute the size of an array, however a common approach is to pass it as a parameter of the function. Other approaches may consist in using particular structures, like `std::vector`, which store the length of the array and eliminate the problem to compute it at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

This line is a at least one problem:

```
int max = sizeof(search_array)/sizeof(search_array[0]);
```

Arrays are not passed through the function, so your declaration:

```
int binary_search(T search_value, T search_array[])
```

... is the same as:

```
int binary_search(T search_value, T *search_array)
```

And thus `max` is size of the pointer divided by the size of element, so in the best case scenario it could be up to 6, but most likely is 0 or 1.

I think in C++ you can pass array by reference and know its size using form of declaration like this:

```
template <size_t array_length>
void foo (const char (&data) [array_length])
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug in your implementation:

```
else if (search_value < search_array[mid])
    max = mid + 1;
```

should be:

```
    max = mid - 1;
```

Comment: While a bug, this is will only degrade performance, and is not the reason for the malfunction, right?

Comment: Probably not. Unless the array is small, then it might access memory beyond the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 2):

This line does not do what you think it does:

```
int max = sizeof(search_array)/sizeof(search_array[0]);
```

Because arrays automatically decay to pointers when passed into a function this will effectively be equal to this:

```
int max = sizeof(void*)/sizeof(search_array[0]);
```

Which is not what you wanted. Either use `std::vector` which stores the size for you or a manual `size_t array_length` argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
int max = sizeof(search_array)/sizeof(search_array[0]);
```

`search_array` is a pointer not an array.

A parameter of type array of `T` in a function prototype is automatically adjusted to a pointer to `T`.

Answer (score 2):

This line is concerning:

```
int max = sizeof(search_array)/sizeof(search_array[0]);
```

`sizeof(search_array)` is going to be the size of a pointer, 4 or 8 bytes depending on the platform.  Typically, I try to avoid the use of `sizeof` on variables.  It plays nicer used on types.  For example, in your case `sizeof(T)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your max needs to be one less as the index starts from 0.